# How does intramolecular hydrogen bonding cause the molecules to be separated from each other?

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

I learnt about intramolecular hydrogen bonding today, which occurs between molecules such as [ortho-nitrophenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrophenol). What I was told is that in case of intramolecular bonding, the molecules separate from each other, opposite of what happens during intermolecular hydrogen bonding.

I don't understand why is this. Why would attraction within a molecule cause separation of the molecules? There is obviously some intermolecular hydrogen bonding present in this case, but I understand that this might be negligible. Still, why should the molecules spread away from each other?

Answer (score 11):

Molecules with **inter**-molecular hydrogen bonds tend to associate with one another, while molecules with **intra**-molecular hydrogen bonds tend to associate with themselves.

*Ortho*- and *para*-nitrophenol are often used as examples of molecules with **intra**- and **inter**-molecular hydrogen bonds respectively (see picture).

[image: ortho/para-nitrophenol and their hydrogen bonds]

Because of their molecular structures the *ortho* isomer can form an intramolecular hydrogen bond with itself, whereas the *para* isomer can only hydrogen bond with another molecule of *p*-nitophenol.  One would say that the *para* isomer associates with other *p*-nitrophenol molecules through hydrogen bonding, whereas the *ortho* isomer associates with itself through hydrogen bonding.  Because the *para* isomer associates with other molecules of *p*-nitrophenol through hydrogen bonding, it takes more energy to break up this association and cause the molecule to melt or boil.  On the other hand, the *ortho* isomer melts and boils at lower temperatures because there are fewer intermolecular forces (such as the hydrogen bonding) holding the *ortho* molecules together.

Comment: Would it be possible to calculate the boiling/melting point of substances in an ideal situation where no hydrogen bonding existed?

Comment: There is no simple method to do this that I am aware of.  There are software packages that attempt to estimate various physical properties of compounds. I'm not sure how accurate or available they are - I think research groups are still trying to improve\refine the packages.

Comment: What I mean to say is: is the boiling point of intramolecular hydrogen bonded substances less than that if there was no hydrogen bonding present?

Comment: If all hydrogen bonds, both inter- and intra-molecular, were removed, then (I think) generally, compounds that had inter-molecular hydrogen bonds would now boil lower and compounds that had intra-molecular hydrogen bonds would now boil higher.

Comment: Ok. That's why I was told. Why would molecules with intra-molecular bonds lower their boiling temp.?

Comment: Because they tend to "stick" to themselves instead of "sticking" to other molecules.  They behave as if they have a lower molecular weight.

Comment: That was my main question. Why would they not stick to other molecules? there would obviously be some intermolecular bonding

Comment: Yes, there is still some intermolecular attraction, but less than there would be without the H-bonding.  I suspect that the H-bonding reduces the dipolar nature of the groups involved (the NO2 and OH groups in this case) and thereby lessens intermolecular electrostatic attractive forces that dipoles can create.