# Physical properties of phenols

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, phenols

Order of increasing boiling point is *p*-nitrophenol > *m*-nitrophenol > *o*-nitrophenol. The difference between bp of *p*- and *o*-nitrophenol is that one form intermolecular hydrogen bonding while other form intramolecular hydrogen bonding. Then what is the reason for high bp of *p*- than *m*-nitrophenol as both form intermolecular hydrogen bonding?

Comment: Related: [Intermolecular Hydrogen Bonding](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14222/7951) and [Strength of types of hydrogen bonds?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4429/7951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of p-nitrophenol the lone pair on oxygen of OH takes part in an extended resonance upto NO2 , more delocalisation of lone pair results into more delta minus on H atom ,so stronger H bonding, whereas  in case of m-nitrophenol it cant have resonace structures upto NO2. Since less delocalisation results in comparitively less delta minus, H bonding is comparitively weak.