# Why o-Nitrophenol is more volatile than p-Nitrophenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, phenols

Why o-Nitrophenol is more steam volatile than p-Nitrophenol?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Physical properties of phenols](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57576/7951), [Intermolecular Hydrogen Bonding](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14222/7951), and [Strength of types of hydrogen bonds?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4429/7951)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

o-Nitrophenol forms intramolecular H bond  whereas molecules of p-Nitrophenol get associated through intermolecular H bond. During boiling, the strong intermolecular H bonding increases the boiling point but intramolecular H bonding cannot do so.

Therefore, o-Nitrophenol is more steam volatile than p-Nitrophenol.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I understand that there is intramolecular hydrogen bonding in o-Nitrophenol. But, how does that prevent it from interacting with surrounding o-Nitrophenol? Consider 3 charges in space. Say Charge 1 interacts with Charge 2 (let's name it 1-2 interaction). The '1-2 interaction' is not going to affect the '1-3 interaction or 3-2 interaction'. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of hydrogen bond.One is intermolecular hydrogen bond and other is intramolecular hydrogen bond.Intermolecular H-Bond increase the melting point,boiling point of compounds having them while the intramolecular H-Bond have mostly opposite effects to that of intermolecular H-Bond(it decreases melting and boiling point).Since o-nitrophenol forms intramolecular H bond it have low Melting boiling point than p-nitrophenol(which form intermolecular H-Bond).That's why o-Nitrophenol is more steam volatile than p-Nitrophenol.